spring integration SFTP SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR issue in spring batch
My spring batch application is trying to download file from mainframe via SFTP (JDK 17)
once the download is over, process continues with read,process and write . This happens twice as there are two categories (A and B) A category is completed , When 'B' category is nearing to completion in writer , the below lines are displayed in the logs post which it takes around 10 mins for the job to complete.
The job usually takes around 10-15 mins, but once these lines come into the log it takes extra 20 mins for the job to complete occupying upto 2Gb (initially it takes 1Gb)
2024-10-22T746.949Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[MMFTPDTP@syb1.dearborn.ford.com/19.59.28.35:222]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600000/600000 ms.
2024-10-22T13:52:59.343Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[MMFTPDTP@syb1.dearborn.ford.com/19.59.28.35:222]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600001/600000 ms.
2024-10-22T13:52:59.944Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[MMFTPDTP@syb1.dearborn.ford.com/19.59.28.35:222]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600493/600000 ms.
2024-10-22T13:53:00.344Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[MMFTPDTP@syb1.dearborn.ford.com/19.59.28.35:222]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600575/600000 ms.
2024-10-22T13:53:04.143Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[MMFTPDTP@syb1.dearborn.ford.com/19.59.28.35:222]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600262/600000 ms.
2024-10-22T13:53:06.940Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[MMFTPDTP@syb1.dearborn.ford.com/19.59.28.35:222]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600190/600000 ms.
2024-10-22T13:53:55.243Z  INFO [,,] 1 --- [-timer-thread-1] o.a.s.client.session.ClientSessionImpl   : Disconnecting(ClientSessionImpl[MMFTPDTP@syb1.dearborn.ford.com/19.59.28.35:222]): SSH2_DISCONNECT_PROTOCOL_ERROR - Detected IdleTimeout after 600219/600000 ms.
2024-10-22T14:16:17.809Z  WARN [,,] 1 --- [lTaskExecutor-2] c.f.p.m.f.l.StepExecutionListenerFactory : Im called from afterStep in createOrderPartStepExecutionListener
2024-10-22T14:16:17.809Z  WARN [,,] 1 --- [lTaskExecutor-2] c.f.p.m.f.l.StepExecutionListenerFactory : Im calling close method for orderprocessor
2024

Since this denotes idle timeout, I tried setting the timeout in DefaultSftpSessionFactory and tried closing by implementing Closeable and using factory.getSession().close().
Previously we didn't get these lines.
It could be due to spring integration sftp upgrade along with jdk 17
FtpClient.java

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class FtpClient{

    @Autowired
    public RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder;

    @Value("${application.sftp.cmms.privatekey:}")
    @Setter
    public String sftpCmmsPrivateKey;

    public SftpRemoteTemplate sftpRemoteTemplate;

    private DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory;

    public RemoteFileTemplate createFtpRemoteFileTemplate(String plantCode) {
        FtpDataDTO ftpData = restClientBuilder.createClient().getFtpData(plantCode);
        if (isSecureFTP()) {
            factory = = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
            factory.setPrivateKey(new ByteArrayResource(sftpCmmsPrivateKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)));
            factory.setUser(ftpData.getUserId().trim());
            factory.setHost(ftpData.getHostname().trim());
            factory.setPort(222);
            factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
            factory.setTimeout(300000);
            sftpRemoteTemplate = new SftpRemoteTemplate(factory);
            return sftpRemoteTemplate;
        } else {
            DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = defaultFtpSessionFactory();
            factory.setPassword(MovisEncryption.decrypt(ftpData.getPassword().trim()));
            factory.setUsername(ftpData.getUserId().trim());
            factory.setHost(ftpData.getHostname().trim());
            factory.setPort(21);
            return new FtpRemoteTemplate(factory);
        }
    }

    private boolean isSecureFTP() {
        return !sftpCmmsPrivateKey.isBlank();
    }

